# Why use sequents?

Tags: logic, proof-theory, motivation, sequent-calculus

In the sequent calculus, the building blocks of a proof are inference rules, which are rules for inferring the validity of certain sequents from other sequents, something like this:

$$\frac{\vec\varphi_1\vdash\vec\psi_1 \qquad \vec\varphi_2\vdash\vec\psi_2}{\vec\varphi_3\vdash\vec\psi_3}$$

However, why sequents, not just propositions?

$$\frac{P \qquad Q}{R}$$

What is the motivation for sequents?

Comment: [Sequent calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus#Sequent_calculus_systems) is a proof system suitable for [Proof Theory](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/proof-theory/), the mathematical study of general properties of mathematical proofs.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I do not understand well. It is written that $A_1, \dots, A_n \vdash B_1, \dots, B_k$ and $\vdash (A_1\wedge\dots\wedge A_n)\rightarrow (B_1\vee\dots \vee B_k)$ are equivalent. Is $\vdash$ necessary?

Comment: The meaning of a sequent is : "if $A_1 \land \ldots \land A_m$, then $B_1 \lor \ldots \lor B_K$". It is the "general form" of an inference and we use $\vdash$ imstead of $\to$ to mean that $\vdash$ is not a (propositional) connective but to express the relation of inference.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Now I understand the difference between $\vdash$ and $\rightarrow$. However, why use something like $\frac{\text{if } A \text{then }B}{\text{if }C \text{then }D}$ as building block of a proof?

Comment: I probably understand. That is because the object of consideration is proof and "if A then B" is the form of proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When dealing with abstract representations of proofs, it is important to distinguish between *hypotheses* and *conclusions*. This is why the turnstile symbol $\vdash$ is used: on its left there are the hypotheses, on its right the conclusions. Note that the turnstile $\vdash$ is not a connective (it is not part of the object language), and the intuitive meaning of a sequent $A_1, \dots, A_n \vdash B_1, \dots, B_m$ is "there is a derivation from the hypothesis $A_1 \land \dots \land A_n$ to the conclusion $B_1 \lor \dots \lor B_m$". A sequent talks about *derivability* of something from something else.

Technically, this distinction between hypotheses and conclusions is needed by inference rules such one the one to introduce the connective $\to$ (implication), which *changes* not only the conclusions but also the hypotheses. Indeed, the "direct" way to prove a sentence of the form $A \to B$ is to have a derivation $\pi$ with hypothesis $A$ and conclusion $B$; from this derivation $\pi$ you can discharge the hypothesis $A$ (i.e. $A$ is not an hypothesis any more) and conclude $A \to B$.

Formally, in the sequent calculus, this is represented by the inference rule $\to_\mathrm{R}$ (right introduction of the implication)
\begin{align}
\frac{\Gamma, A \vdash B, \Delta}{\Gamma \vdash A \to B, \Delta}\to_R
\end{align}

---

It is clear that on the left of the turnstile a finite *set* of formulas is required (technically, it can be a finite multiset or a finite sequence): these formulas represent the hypotheses, which can be several.

For technical reasons, at least in classical logic, it is crucial$^*$ that there is a finite set (or more precisely, a finite multiset or a finite sequence) of formulas also on the right of the turnstile, for the conclusions. Indeed, inference rules such as 
\begin{align}
\frac{\Gamma \vdash A, B, \Delta}{\Gamma \vdash A \lor B, \Delta}\lor_R \qquad
\frac{\Gamma\vdash A, A, \Delta}{\Gamma \vdash A, \Delta}\mathrm{ctr}_R
\end{align}
(where it is important to have more than one formula on the right of the turnstile) distinguish the sequent calculus for classical logic from the one for weaker logics such as intuitionistic.

---

${}^*$ More precisely, it is crucial if you don't want to lose good structural properties of your proof system, such as symmetry between left and right, [analiticity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_proof) with the subformula property and [cut-elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cut-elimination_theorem).

Comment: Is it strictly true that it is "crucial" for a sequent calculus for classical logic to allow more than one formula on the right? Add to the one-formula-on-the-right intuitionist logic a version of double negation elimination and you get a classical calculus. Of course in doing that you loose some features it is nice to have.

Comment: @PeterSmith - Yes, thank you for the comment. I added a footnote to clarify my point. For the sake of completeness, it might be also mentioned that in a logic such as the classical one, where negation is involutive and implication is definable by other connectives, actually sequents can be only one-side and the turnstile is actually superfluous. But I guess this is not the main interest of the OP.